# Should I Index every URL to google?

Tags: magento2, url, seo

I'm running a shoe store, so I have lots of attributes creating a lot of different indexable URLS's (shoe sizes, colours etc) - Should I submit all of these url's? Will it bring an SEO benefit or not

Comment: This looks more like a pure SEO question than a Magento question.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't since the content of the URLs only varies slightly. 
Better tell Google that these are products with variations.

Google Video: Rich Snippets: Product Search
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-rRxKSm2ic